# How to Fix Loading Issues in Unity Reflect and Correct Red/Blue Box Errors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, reflection

red boxes around objects and they wont load in correctly and some stay blue and never load.. i have tried exporting it again and to different projects locally and on the cloud.

I in in the eastern us area and have tried on mobile and on different computers and still get the same issues also tried clearing the cache.

trying to get it to load.

Comment: sounds like you arent exporting enough bits of it